# Nuget Pack in Azure Pipelines: The method or operation is not implemented

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

I am trying to build a DotNetCore project and push the package to Azure Artifacts.

The Azure-Pipelines.yml I have is the following:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  buildPlatform: 'any cpu'
  version: '1.0.0'

steps:

- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Install'
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '2.2.105'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Restore'
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/*.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build'
  inputs:
    command: build
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Pack'
  inputs:
    command: pack
    versioningScheme: byEnvVar
    versionEnvVar: version

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Push'
  inputs:
    command: push
    publishVstsFeed: 'myfeed'
```

It fails on task **Pack** with the error:

```
Caching tool: NuGet 4.1.0 x64
Found tool in cache: NuGet 4.1.0 x64
Resolved from tool cache: 4.1.0
Using version: 4.1.0
Found tool in cache: NuGet 4.1.0 x64
Attempting to pack file: /home/vsts/work/1/s/MyProject.csproj
[command]/usr/bin/mono /opt/hostedtoolcache/NuGet/4.1.0/x64/nuget.exe pack /home/vsts/work/1/s/MyProject.csproj -NonInteractive -OutputDirectory /home/vsts/work/1/a -Properties Configuration=Release -version 1.0.0 -Verbosity Detailed
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
NuGet Version: 4.1.0.2450
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.CallSite.Target(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,object)
Attempting to build package from 'MyProject.csproj'.
  at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid1[T0] (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite site, T0 arg0) [0x00108] in <48b97f13fd854060ad87a12d847b0428>:0 
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from '/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin'. Use option -MSBuildVersion to force nuget to use a specific version of MSBuild.
  at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.ResolveTargetPath () [0x00345] in <d0f788a4af354971807e5d8ca6fc682e>:0 
  at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.BuildProject () [0x0016e] in <d0f788a4af354971807e5d8ca6fc682e>:0 
  at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.CreateBuilder (System.String basePath, NuGet.Versioning.NuGetVersion version, System.String suffix, System.Boolean buildIfNeeded, NuGet.Packaging.PackageBuilder builder) [0x00015] in <d0f788a4af354971807e5d8ca6fc682e>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildFromProjectFile (System.String path) [0x00140] in <d0f788a4af354971807e5d8ca6fc682e>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildPackage (System.String path) [0x00033] in <d0f788a4af354971807e5d8ca6fc682e>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildPackage () [0x00021] in <d0f788a4af354971807e5d8ca6fc682e>:0 
  at NuGet.CommandLine.PackCommand.ExecuteCommand () [0x001fe] in <d0f788a4af354971807e5d8ca6fc682e>:0 
  at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.ExecuteCommandAsync () [0x00000] in <d0f788a4af354971807e5d8ca6fc682e>:0 
  at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute () [0x000b7] in <d0f788a4af354971807e5d8ca6fc682e>:0 
  at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore (System.String workingDirectory, System.String[] args) [0x001f3] in <d0f788a4af354971807e5d8ca6fc682e>:0 
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.CallSite.Target(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,object)
  at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid1[T0] (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite site, T0 arg0) [0x00108] in <48b97f13fd854060ad87a12d847b0428>:0 
  at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.ResolveTargetPath () [0x00345] in <d0f788a4af354971807e5d8ca6fc682e>:0 
  at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.BuildProject () [0x0016e] in <d0f788a4af354971807e5d8ca6fc682e>:0 
  at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.CreateBuilder (System.String basePath, NuGet.Versioning.NuGetVersion version, System.String suffix, System.Boolean buildIfNeeded, NuGet.Packaging.PackageBuilder builder) [0x00015] in <d0f788a4af354971807e5d8ca6fc682e>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildFromProjectFile (System.String path) [0x00140] in <d0f788a4af354971807e5d8ca6fc682e>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildPackage (System.String path) [0x00033] in <d0f788a4af354971807e5d8ca6fc682e>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildPackage () [0x00021] in <d0f788a4af354971807e5d8ca6fc682e>:0 
  at NuGet.CommandLine.PackCommand.ExecuteCommand () [0x001fe] in <d0f788a4af354971807e5d8ca6fc682e>:0 
  at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.ExecuteCommandAsync () [0x00000] in <d0f788a4af354971807e5d8ca6fc682e>:0 
  at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute () [0x000b7] in <d0f788a4af354971807e5d8ca6fc682e>:0 
  at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore (System.String workingDirectory, System.String[] args) [0x001f3] in <d0f788a4af354971807e5d8ca6fc682e>:0)
##[error]An error ocurred while trying to pack the files.
##[section]Finishing: Pack
```

I tried many configurations but I am not able to remove the error.

What am I missing?

Comment: Even if you're doing something wrong, NuGet shouldn't give you a NotImplementedException. Please report this https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues

Comment: but given it's a .NET Core project, you should use `dotnet pack` rather than `mono nuget.exe pack`

Comment: @zivkan I just reported and I was also able to solve it using dotnet pack. Thank you.

Comment: Here is the link to the issue logged on GitHub:  [Nuget Pack in Azure Pipelines: The method or operation is not implemented](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7971)

Comment: dotnet pack does not work if there are project references as it would not include the referenced projects in the build output. But nuget pack allows that with IncludeReferencedProjects  options. So yea if possible we can use dotnet pack but it doesn't solve the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Above problem can be solved by using

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest' // which is 20.04
```

I tried this and it solved the problem. For clarity i used the MS hosted agent and agent version is 2.200.2

May be using the Self hosted agent(missing nuget installation or in correct version of nuget) or a diff version of ubuntu is the cause of the issue.

*** EDIT ****

I recently faced this issue again and this time we were using self hosted agent rather than MS hosted and i solved it by building the project, and pushing the nuget inside docker only.

Below is the sample dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04 as base
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install gnupg ca-certificates -y
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
RUN echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install mono-roslyn mono-complete mono-dbg msbuild nuget -yq
RUN apt install wget -y
RUN wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
RUN dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
RUN rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb
RUN apt install -y apt-transport-https
RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install dotnet-sdk-3.1 -y
RUN apt install dotnet-runtime-3.1 -y

FROM base as build
WORKDIR /app
ARG PATTOKEN
ARG SEMVER
COPY . .
RUN sed -i "s|PATTOKEN|$PATTOKEN|i" ./nuget.config
RUN dotnet build "<csproj path>" -c Release
RUN nuget pack "<csproj path>" -Properties Configuration=Release -Version $SEMVER -Verbosity Detailed  -IncludeReferencedProjects -OutputDirectory /app/package

FROM build AS final
WORKDIR /app/package
COPY --from=build /app/package .
RUN dotnet nuget push "./*.nupkg" --api-key az --source "<nuget feed uri>"
RUN rm -rf "./*.nupkg"
```

Basically based upon ubuntu docker image, i have installed required dependencies and built the project.